# LINQ to Entities: nullable datetime in where clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a where clause that looks up child objects on an entity:

```
var Lookup = row.Offenses.Where(x => x.Desc == co.Desc && x.Action == co.Action && x.AppealYN == co.AppealYN && x.OffDate == co.OffDate).ToList();
```

Sometimes the `co.OffDate` can be null, which will cause an exception.  Right now, the only way I can think of to get around that, is to use an if statement:

```
 if (co.OffDate.HasValue)
                                {
 var Lookup = row.Offenses.Where(x => x.Desc == co.Desc && x.Action == co.Action && x.AppealYN == co.AppealYN && x.OffDate == co.OffDate).ToList();
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                     var Lookup = row.Offenses.Where(x => x.Desc == co.Desc && x.Action == co.Action && x.AppealYN == co.AppealYN).ToList();
                                }
```

Is there anyway I can re-write the linq query to accomplish what the if statement does?  I still want to do a lookup, even if the `co.OffDate` is null.

Comment: In your database, is the datetime field nullable?

Comment: So do you **ever** want to get back `Offenses` where the result of Offenses all OffenseDate's are null?

Comment: Yes, I want to get a result back, even if the offensedate is null.

Comment: Is it co.OffenseDate or co.OffDate?  It appears both ways in your question.  I assumed co.OffDate for my answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could insert a ternary into your Where filter:

```
var Lookup = row.Offenses
  .Where(x => 
    x.Desc == co.Desc 
    && x.Action == co.Action 
    && x.AppealYN == co.AppealYN 
    && (co.OffDate.HasValue ? x.OffDate == co.OffDate : true)
  ).ToList();
```

Comment: There we go.  This is exactly what I need.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I would rewrite it to be more readable (in my opinion):

```
var query = row.Offenses.Where(x => x.Desc == co.Desc 
                                    && x.Action == co.Action 
                                    && x.AppealYN == co.AppealYN)
if (co.OffenseDate.HasValue)
{
  query = query.Where(x.OffDate == co.OffenseDate);
}

var Lookup = query.ToList();
```